# Are OP edit rejects real?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have seen a couple of times where my suggested edit to a post gets accepted by other reviewers, yet rejected by the OP. If I remember correctly, if OP rejects, its a veto and the edit is fully rejected.

If I also remember correctly, if the OP edits the post while you have an edit suggestion, it also gets rejected (via the Community user?)

If I see an edit rejection by the OP, can I be sure that it's actually the OP looking at the edit and rejecting or could there be a more byzantine opaque process causing this?

Comment: IIRC, the OP is the only one who can take actions that would cause that message.

Comment: I think even if OP rollbacks (rolls back) your edit within certain period, it will be marked rejected retrospectively. [citation needed]

Comment: @NisargShah Here's a post about someone requesting a change for that feature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296166/user-experience-of-overriding-communitys-decision-on-suggested-edit

Comment: I've had numerous edits rejected by the community user because the OP has not accepted my edit and then performed the exact it

Answer (score 5):

> If I see a edit rejection by the OP, can I be sure that its actually the OP looking at the edit...

Yes.

You are correct that when an edit by the OP conflicts with your edit that your edit is rejected by the Community User and [suggested edit rejections by the Community User do not count against you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste).